# C# Unit testing with Fake database context using a HashSet (pluralsight code)(New Q)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

**The short version:**

In this video, Mr. Scott Allen [explains how to test a controller](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-tdd&mode=live&clip=3&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro).
But he does not show the full code of the class: `FakeDbContext`.
Is there someone who can help me finish it? He shows the class at, 06:15 min in the video for "testing controllers".

**The long version**

At school I have a elective where we learn C#. My exam project is a ASP site using MVC3.
To learn it fast, i have seen videos from PluralSight. My question is about some code that are in [this video](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-tdd&mode=live&clip=3&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro)
He explains how to test controllers. So i tried:
I have made a controller which has a simple index method:

```
public class Round1Controller : Controller
{
    IDbContext _db;

    public Round1Controller()
    {
        _db = new Entities();
    }
    
    public Round1Controller(IDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.ELECTIVES.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

As you can see i have already tried to make a context.
The index method is the one i want to TEST.
The next thing he does is to make a class called, `FakeDbContext`, in the test project.

But sadly he only show a part of the code, and i have used a lot of hours trying to figure out how he creates a `get` method to a `HashSet`.

Here is the code that you can see from the video:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using EESS.Models;

namespace EESS.Tests
{
class FakeDbContext : IDbContext
{
    public IQueryable<Restaurant> Restaurants
    {
        get { return _map.Get<Restaurant>().asQueryable(); }
        set { _map.Use<Restaurant>(value); }
    }
    public IQueryable<Review> Reviews
    {
        get { return _map.Get<Review>().asQueryable(); }
        set { _map.Use<Review>(value); }
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangesSaved = true;
        return 0;
    }

    public bool ChangesSaved { get; set; }

    public T Attach<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _map.Get<T>().Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }
    public T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _map.Get<T>().Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public T Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
    {
        _map.Get<T>().Remove(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    SetMap _map = new SetMap();

    class SetMap : KeyedCollection<Type, object>
    {
        public HashSet<T> Use<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceData)
        {
            var set = new HashSet<T>(sourceData);
            if (Contains(typeof(T)))
            {
                Remove(typeof(T));
            }
            Add(set);
            return set;
        }
    }
}
}
```

To end the long version, my problem is i get a error on `_Map.Get`.
`Does not contain a definition or extension method`.

**EDIT! PART 2:**

After @xelibrion great answer it finally worked.

But then another problem come up.

The IDbContext class looks like this:

```
public interface IDbContext
    {
        IQueryable<ELECTIVES> ELECTIVES { get; }
        int SaveChanges();
        T Attach<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        T Add<T>(T entity) where T : class;
        T Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class;
    }
```

When i add this interface to my Entities Class it offcouse expect me to implement the methods.
PluralSight implements them like this:

```
public DbSet<ELECTIVES> electives { get; set; }

    IQueryable<ELECTIVES> IDbContext.ELECTIVES
    {
        get { return electives; }
    }

    int IDbContext.SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChanges();
    }
    
    T IDbContext.Add<T>(T entity)
    {
        return Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
    
    T IDbContext.Delete<T>(T entity)
    {
        return Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
    
    T IDbContext.Attach<T>(T entity)
    {
        
        var entry = Entry(entity);
        entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        return entity;
        return Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }
```

But my "_dbModel.Designer.cs" class from my entity model does not know what Set and Entry is, and only suggest i make a method stub. There are a lot more code in this class, so if its need just ask for the rest :) I have changed Restaurants to Electives since thats the table name i my DB.

Is it a "using" i have forgotten? I have seen the video again, and he does not have a method stub in his DB class.

Comment: @casperOne Thanks for the edit. It looks a bit easier to read now! :)

Comment: Not a problem; nothing personal against "hello" and "thank you", but the general [guidance is to not include them in posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @casperOne Thats Cool. Just seemed more "personal" than just throwing a question out there :)

Comment: It's possible he is using mock objects?

Comment: @Amedio I have seen the video over and over again, and he never talks about Mock objects. I have read a little bit about them, but the way he does it, sounds to me to be smarter and more dynamic than mock objects. Correct me if i'm wrong. :)

Comment: For anyone who is still using this, the full source code can be found at http://odetofood.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose full version of SetMap class should look like this

```
class SetMap : KeyedCollection<Type, object>
{
    public HashSet<T> Use<T>(IEnumerable<T> sourceData)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<T>(sourceData);
        if (Contains(typeof(T)))
        {
            Remove(typeof(T));
        }
        Add(set);
        return set;
    }

    public HashSet<T> Get <T>()
    {
        return (HashSet<T>) this[typeof(T)];
    }

    protected override Type GetKeyForItem(object item)
    {
        return item.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks great. I'll try it tomorrow morning and see if it works :) Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It works great" :D Thank you so much! :D I hope you maybe can help my again. I have updated the main question with a part 2.

Comment: I guess Set<T>() from second question is combination of SetMap's GET<T>() and Use<T>() methods, but I have no idea what Entry method is

Comment: Okay.. I'll try and find a solution.. Thanks for your effort! :D